# Why is extern required for forward declaration of global variables but not for functions when using them from other files in C++

Tags: c++, global-variables, extern, linkage

From what I already know, both global non-constant variables and functions have external linkage by default. So they can be used from other files with the help of forward declaration . For example:

<other.cpp>

```cpp
int myNum{888};

int getAnInt()
{
    return 999;
}
```

<main.cpp>

```cpp
#include <iostream>

extern int myNum;  // "extern" keyword is required.
int getAnInt();    // "extern" keyword is NOT required.

int main()
{
    std::cout << getAnInt() << "\n";
    std::cout << myNum << "\n";
}
```

However, if no `extern` before `int myNum;`. This will happen:

```
duplicate symbol '_myNum' in:
    /path~~/main.o
    /path~~/other.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
```

So my question is why `extern` is required for `myNum`? Don't global non-constant variables have external linkage by default?

Comment: because `extern` turns variable definition into declaration, while `int getAnInt();` is already a declaration. You are allowed to have multiple declarations (as long as they are identical), but only one definition for each entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is a difference between

```
int getAnInt();
```

and

```
int getAnInt() { ... }
```

Namely the brackets themselves, and as such there is no need for a marker like `extern` to differentiate between the two.

Particularly, the former is a declaration, which just states that `getAnInt` exists and returns an `int` etc, whereas the latter gives it its definition.